# Dealing with a PublicKey object in Java

Tags: java, rsa

First, thanks for the time, and also some patience since I´m a noob in this subject...
I have a PublicKey object:

```
Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18077203024541758363929020498733829335491380051700307922133794962061975747420394877143889885945336305414295314139507244695177887549094887061986620463327220586346030432731550617421168238140740600157137764348364595070740870977422155213465409492752709350141858141989090093641680035205975043549124382974765930336756768548921056751935659732417661594872253800976031104054204421629711597470770033907934006101453865340621763385927121144139876123093050849040638804744781745077880021130241262817005818066815987603380244330904985993553253768481242544555268132089382269330678737161421709242927983939704722774178497866252217753513
  public exponent: 65537
```

and I need to get it like this:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjzLzvHyJXagAfmQNgRSDJ3vIStkpy3I3 FOW4xRx+WkoEbOV9K7WFgDB2PTvl+fAHhY5mvGGhZZfGGO0THEFZdBqDlZEZqbg6uW/QDh4cDdJb NFhAzIeXSPFSdLZ15i5YIzcPVKSlm7Cuf0ogUOq8qXnlEdfd47mrwp7KrT2vtgkrLpkyKiUE6e/I NrQYgPADSv0QyTBgZCxqt5wM70IQtjEi4EcSzgwCwG0aEbjo8Imv42BH1Zk8igs1A/tasLeSHAMY xpqAvGf8zHncSsAqdzJmziRn1tZUYN2WHKpW2mWuDVy5ACYePMv7IzzvTMAWjC7G6c8y5my+MmMe QmAfqQIDAQAB
```

(For what I get that is a correct example)

I really don´t know how to handle this kind of object so I really don´t know if it´s something pretty dumb or hard to achieve.

Edit: (Further Explanation)
In this case I´m dealing with a PublicKey Object that I get working with the net.ripe.commons.certification library since I need to parse the fields of an End Entity Certificate.
When I get the Public Key I get it with the `.getPublicKey()` of a X509cert, and I see as it is show in the first code posted. I need to store it in a field in a database, if I for instance use `.getEncode().toString()`, it gives my something that is not right.
I already know for other application in the web that the second code (which is how I want to save it in the db) corresponds to the first one.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain, please?

Comment: I explain a little more, I´m kinda out in this subject so I really don´t know when is few of information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was expected it was my mistake...
In this case the problem was with the ... `.getEncode().toString()`, I was using

```
String key = Base64.encodeBase64(x509rc.getPublicKey().getEncoded()).toString()
```

when the correct use would be

```
String key = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(x509rc.getPublicKey().getEncoded()))
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try and store it as a string, but as a byte array, or failing that, as something like a Base64-encoded value if you're set on using a string.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using a Base64 encoded value, but since I wasn´t getting anything right I stop using it, thanks to you pointing it out I try again and realize my real problem